# Yarn Commands to trace issues or errors

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I tried to connect to EMR master node using SSH and based on application id I want to tract the issues but I don't have knowledge on YARN commands so where can I get or find YARN commands etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to know any yarn commands since logs are regular text files (sometimes archived). [Most of them are located in `/mnt/var/log/`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html). For example, log files of execution steps are here: `/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/`.

If you want to find executors' logs then you should ssh to core nodes and look for application logs under `/mnt/var/log/application/`.

Besides that, EMR by default is configured to [archive log files to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html#emr-manage-view-web-log-files-s3)